# How can I improve this ugly Postgresql query generated by my possibly poor Django code?

Tags: python, sql, django, database-performance, django-postgresql

I'm doing this in a Django view:

```
def by_gear(gear):
    types = {
        'imaging_telescopes': Telescope,
        'guiding_telescopes': Telescope,
        'mounts': Mount,
        'imaging_cameras': Camera,
        'guiding_cameras': Camera,
        'focal_reducers': FocalReducer,
        'software': Software,
        'filters': Filter,
        'accessories': Accessory,
    }
    filters = reduce(operator.or_, [Q(**{'%s__gear_ptr__pk' % t: gear.pk}) for t in types])
    images = Image.objects.filter(filters).distinct()

    return images
```

That's because I have a gear item, and I don't know what kind of gear it is (telescope, camera, etc). It's a base model.

So I'm ORring all possibilities with that `reduce`. Since all the subclasses of Gear, which are also Django Models, share the `pk` with the base class Gear, I can do that. I know it's not very readable, and I'm not explaining it too well, but if you look at the SQL generated below, it will be clear.

I'm trying to fetch all Images taken with that piece of equipment (Gear), so see if its `pk` is in `image__telescopes`, `image__imaging_cameras`, and so on.

However, that ends up producing this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "astrobin_image"."id") FROM "astrobin_image"

LEFT OUTER JOIN "astrobin_image_imaging_telescopes"
ON ("astrobin_image"."id" = "astrobin_image_imaging_telescopes"."image_id")

LEFT OUTER JOIN "astrobin_image_guiding_telescopes"
ON ("astrobin_image"."id" = "astrobin_image_guiding_telescopes"."image_id")

LEFT OUTER JOIN "astrobin_image_software"
ON ("astrobin_image"."id" = "astrobin_image_software"."image_id")

LEFT OUTER JOIN "astrobin_image_filters"
ON ("astrobin_image"."id" = "astrobin_image_filters"."image_id")

LEFT OUTER JOIN "astrobin_image_imaging_cameras"
ON ("astrobin_image"."id" = "astrobin_image_imaging_cameras"."image_id")

LEFT OUTER JOIN "astrobin_image_mounts"
ON ("astrobin_image"."id" = "astrobin_image_mounts"."image_id")

LEFT OUTER JOIN "astrobin_image_focal_reducers"
ON ("astrobin_image"."id" = "astrobin_image_focal_reducers"."image_id")

LEFT OUTER JOIN "astrobin_image_accessories"
ON ("astrobin_image"."id" = "astrobin_image_accessories"."image_id")

LEFT OUTER JOIN "astrobin_image_guiding_cameras"
ON ("astrobin_image"."id" = "astrobin_image_guiding_cameras"."image_id")

WHERE ("astrobin_image_imaging_telescopes"."telescope_id" = 4723
OR "astrobin_image_guiding_telescopes"."telescope_id" = 4723
OR "astrobin_image_software"."software_id" = 4723
OR "astrobin_image_filters"."filter_id" = 4723
OR "astrobin_image_imaging_cameras"."camera_id" = 4723
OR "astrobin_image_mounts"."mount_id" = 4723
OR "astrobin_image_focal_reducers"."focalreducer_id" = 4723
OR "astrobin_image_accessories"."accessory_id" = 4723
OR "astrobin_image_guiding_cameras"."camera_id" = 4723 )
```

So this query takes over 2 seconds... Can you suggest a way to improve this mess?

Comment: First off.. `Q(**{'%s__gear_ptr__pk' % t: gear.pk}) for t in types` can be `[Q('%s__gear_ptr__pk' % t = gear.pk) for t in types]`

Comment: Since you are doing a simple `and`, you dont even need `Q` . Just do `", ".join(['%s__gear_ptr__pk = %s' % (t, gear.pk) for t in types])`

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't this query returning an incorrect count anyway? To get the count you should be doing `select count(*) from (select 1 from tbl1 where id = ? union all select 1 from tbl2 where id = ? union all … ) as sub;`

Comment: Weird model structure, why not to have one base `Gear` model with `image_id` field?